# How to convert String date time to DateTime in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

We have date-time in GMT and want to convert it in EST. when we are trying below xsl, we are getting an error.

FORG0001: Invalid dateTime value "05/26/20 14:58" (Non-numeric year component)

**Here is my xsl-**

```
            <xsl:variable name="estDateTime">
                <xsl:call-template name="convertGMTToEST">
                <xsl:with-param name="gmtDateTime" select="'05/26/20 14:58'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            
    <xsl:template name="convertGMTToEST">
      <xsl:param name="gmtDateTime" />
        <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime($gmtDateTime),xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT5H'))"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output-**
we want this date time to be converted into the corresponding EST date-time.

**Note-**
we are using xslt 2.0 processor.

Comment: The XPath/XSLT 2 and later `xs:date` format is e.g. `2020-06-26`, the `xs:dateTime` format e.g. `2020-06-26T14:58:00` so you need to break up the string input you get to extract the relevant components and reorder/reformat them to construct the right input format for `xs:dateTime`. The `substring` functions or the `replace` function or `tokenize` or `analyze-string` call all help with that.

Answer (score 0):

`xs:dateTime(replace('05/26/20 14:58', '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})', '20$3-$1-$2T$4:$5:00'))` might work for the particular sample but of course if there is any variation in the input format with four digit years or seconds in the time part you will probably need more than a single, simple replace call.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `saxon:parse-dateTime()` extension function:

https://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-dateTime

Requires Saxon-PE or higher, Saxon 10 onwards.

Comment: we are using saxon 9.9.  With Saxon 9.9, do we have any way to convert DateTime from  GMT to DateTime in EST?

Comment: Converting timezones is no problem with the standard XSLT date/time libraries. It's parsing non-standard US-format m/d/y date representations that's the issue.